# GUI for scientific plotting with d3.js, similar to Veusz or Matlab plotting window?

Tags: javascript, gui, diagram, plotting

I am looking for something like the awesome plotting tool Veusz (https://veusz.github.io/screenshots/) or the Matlab figure window in JavaScript.

The JavaScript library d3.js seems to be very powerful and is used/extended by several plotting libraries, e.g. nvd3. I would like to use it for scientific plots and data analysis.

Does an open source plotting GUI for d3.js already exist? Or would I have to develop one?

Elements in a plot should serve as "plot handles": if I click on them, a property window should show the corresponding properties. If I click for example on an axis I will see axis properties like the min and max value and the tick distance. Changing those properties will change the plot. If I click on a curve, I am able to change the curve color and the symbol style and so on.

*Edit*
The following old question points to some interesting projects. However I still did not found what I am looking for:

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-good-GUI-for-D3-js-and-other-javascript-visualization-libraries

Answer (score 1):

I decided to implement the plotting window feature for my d3.js plots in Java.
(Since Java is the language of my main project "Treez" and I prefer to write type save code. In order to use d3.js from within Java I use a javafx-d3 wrapper.)

If some of you want to develop a d3.js GUI in another language (e.g. directly in JavaScript) my project might serve as a starting point. It took me some time to find out how to exactly create minor ticks, log scales and so on with d3.js.

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treez/tree/master/treezResults/src/org/treez/results/atom
[image]

Comment: In the mean time, code editors in JavaScript improved a lot. I started to port treez to treezjs, using the orion editor: https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treezjs